# Umbraco Virtual Nodes

Tags: .net, virtual, umbraco, nodes

I've current got a content structure similar to this:

```
Content

- Home
  - Articles
    - Article 1
    - Article 2
  - About
  - Contact

- Users
  - User 1
    - Articles
      - Article 3
      - Article 4
  - User 2
    - Articles
      - Article 5
```

In summary I have a site with a page that display links to the articles beneath it (1 and 2). I want to allow users to signup and add their own articles. So I have a registration script that creates an umbraco user, then creates the User node in the Users folder above, each user gets a folder beneath them to add their own articles. The script sets the start node of each user to there corresponding user node in the content tree.

To illustrate, User 1 just sees:

```
- User 1
  - Articles
    - Article 3
    - Article 4
```

Each article belonging to a user has a url like "/Users/User 1/Articles/Article 3" however, I want to be able to create a virtual node under the Content/Articles folder so that the url is "/Articles/Article 3". Can this be done? And are virtual nodes the right approach to take?

I also dont like the fact that the Users folder still has a navigateable URL even though it exists outside the content tree. Perhaps there is a better approach for this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done (of course - it's Umbraco).

Here's how you could go about it:

- [umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/webconfig) set to `true` in the web.config, and slightly change your structure:

  > ```
  > Site
  >   Home
  >   AllArticles
  >     Article 1
  >     Article 2
  >   About
  >   Contact
  > Users
  >   User 1
  >     Articles
  >       Article 3
  >   User 2
  >   ...
  > ```
- Use *Manage hostnames*  on `Site` to define the site's hostname (right-click on the node).
- Configure a redirect from `Site` to `Home` (there is a package for redirects)
- The `Users` section should be completely out of the usually navigatable node structure and therefore not be visible.
- Document type `AllArticles` uses a template which displays all articles of all users by default (query by document type), and when called with a parameter (or prettier when using url rewriting) identifying uniquely the article, shows the article.

  - Of course different users may use the same name for their articles, so you won't be able to simply use the article's name to identify it.

Comment: Hi Marapet, thanks for your response! Looks like it is what I need. I shall go through the steps you have mentioned and report back. One thing i'm also curious about is trying this with multiple levels. For example if User1/Articles/Article1 had a /Comments/ folder underneath. Im assuming I could perhaps create an Articles/Comments/ page in the main section, and pass in a parameter to define which articles comments to show? But this could get quite messy? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, this may get messy, it's always good to keep it simple... Also: Who comments? Do they have access to Umbraco UI? Or do you have a publicly accessible form which adds and publishes nodes? Previewing user articles may be an other problem to solve.

Comment: Ah yes previewing too. For this, the article would need a navigable URL? As for comments, it was just to illustrate that if each article were to have sub-folders it could become hard to manage. I will give your solution a try, as I think I would still like to move to a solution where I can create non-navigable content but think I may need a more expandable solution for these "virtual" nodes. (However, since your response does solve the original question I'm quite happy to mark as solution, or update my question :) ) Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean by _Non-navigable content_ ? You can simply not assign a template for those document types. Or a _NullTemplate_ (empty template, I remember having some publishing problems with nodes without a template assigned in some version of Umbraco), or _NotFoundTemplate_ (to return 404 if the url is called).

Comment: I mean content that the user can't navigate to, from the front-end. Yes not applying a template could achieve that, but from what i understand in your answer, the first 3 steps achieve this without the need for using empty/no templates. Unless I have misunderstood?